Ubuntu 24 Upgrade: Tracker Miner Failing Due to Landlock Issue, System Stuck at Black Screen
After upgrading from Ubuntu 22 to Ubuntu 24 on my desktop, my system now fails to boot properly. The boot process gets stuck at a black screen with an X-shaped cursor. Upon inspecting the system logs, I noticed the following error related to tracker-miner-fs:
tracker-miner-fs-3: Could not get landlock supported ABI: Operation not supported
Refusing to extract file data since Landlock could not be enabled. Update your kernel to fix this warning.

System Details:
Ubuntu Version: Upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04
Desktop Environment: GNOME (default)
Kernel Version: 5.14.0.1052-oem

I’ve tried all packages (sudo apt update) using the TTY console (Ctrl + Alt + F3), but the issue persists.
This is fixed in kernel version 6.8.0-41-generic for me.
Questions:
Is this issue related to the Landlock feature in the kernel? How can I enable or properly configure it?
Are there any known bugs with the tracker-miner-fs service or the Landlock security module in Ubuntu 24?
Is this a regression or a known issue with Ubuntu 24?

Thank you in advance!

My machine automatically booted 5.14 out of the box. I had to manually choose to boot 6.8 via GRUB. There still seem to be things broken in 6.8 - my wifi doesn't seem to work. Also, I assume support for 5.14 is not discontinued? If so, why is it an option?

5.14 is an option because it's installed. You control that. (We don't reach into your machine and turn things on and off.) So 6.8 gets you a proper, working graphical desktop...but without WiFi?

Yep. I'll file a separate issue for the wifi problem. Perhaps there should be some warning that Ubuntu 24 doesn't work with specific major kernel versions (is all of 5.x broken)? The wifi issue also seems to be related to tracker-miner-fs, although I basically just threw up my hands and gave up yesterday without diving deep into the issue.

Kernel 5.x is not broken. 24.04 uses features that 5.x lacked when it was created years ago. The most famous warning, written for Debian but applicable to all Debian-based OS, including Ubuntu: https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian . Kernel 5.14 on a 24.04 system suggested a possible or unintentional FrankenSystem (FrankenDebian)
